# toupper function in C with for loop

Tags: c, string, loops

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work as I wanted it to.

```
int main()
{
    char sentence[] = "this will be capitalised";
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(sentence); i++)
    {
        toupper(sentence[i]);
        putchar(sentence[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return (0);
}
```

I end up with this:

```
this will be capitalised

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thank you

Comment: `toupper` returns the uppercased letter. You have to assign back to the source string: `sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);`

Comment: or `putchar(toupper(sentence[i]))` if the result isn't needed any more.

Comment: Technically it should be `toupper((unsigned char)sentence[i])`, in case we're on an EBCDIC machine

Comment: @M.M On EBCDIC machine, the `unsigned char` is typically _not_ needed as `char` is usually unsigned there.  It is on other machines with the common case where `char` is signed, that needs the `(unsigned char)` cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
   toupper(sentence[i]);
```

with this one:

```
   sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);
```

The problem with your code is that `toupper` does not do the conversion in place, instead it returns the converted letter as its return value.

If you don't want to modify the string and you are only want to print it in uppercase form, then use WolfieeifloW's solution.

**Edit**: As others have pointed out, `strlen` is slow function (it has to scan the entire string, so it takes `Θ(n)` time) and the solution presented here will prevent the compiler from doing the smart optimization to evaluate it once. So it would be preferable to preevaluate it your self, like so:

```
int len = strlen(sentence);

for (i=0; i<len; i++)
```

Comment: This code modifies `sentence[]`, which of course, the OP wants/needs.  A side effect is that code can not then optimize out the call to `strlen()` and thus oblige repeated `strlen()` calls.   Result: `O(n*n)` run-time.  Changing the loop end condition would make for improved code.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a while loop:

```
int i = 0;    

while(sentence[i]) {
    putchar(toupper(sentence[i]));
    i++;
}
```

This also helps to avoid computing the `strlen` of `sentence[]` every loop.

Comment: Upvoted. That's much nicer: it avoids the repeated computation of `strlen` that I allude to.

Comment: @redneb's answer is better, but I would put `putchar(toupper(sentence[i]));`

Comment: Why not `for (i = 0; sentence[i]; i++)`?

Comment: @WolfieeifloW - yes, there is a reason to downvote - though I did not.  The OP didn't read the man page for toupper, that's a fatal error.

Answer (score 5):

`toupper(sentence[i]);` does not *modify* its argument, but returns it. The solution is therefore to replace the first statement in your loop body with

`sentence[i] = toupper((unsigned char)sentence[i]);`

I've also snook in an `(unsigned char)` cast for portability (acknowledge @M.M). (EBCDIC encoding requires 8 bits for alphanumeric characters.)

Also, because you are mutating `sentence`, I imagine that no compiler on earth will optimise out the multiple calls of `strlen(sentence)` to a single call. Your O(N) algorithm has suddenly become O(N * N)! Consider pre-computing this, running the loop backwards, or ace it by using `sentence[i]` as the stopping expression? (Acknowledge @nwellnhof).